# Activate rgrep from isearch

Tags: emacs, grep, isearch

I'd like to be able to switch from an `isearch` query directly into `rgrep` (interactively) such that `rgrep` defaults to using for the full `isearch` query string. The default behavior of `rgrep` is to use the symbol under the cursor, but this doesn't work well if the `isearch` query contains spaces.

This recipe from EmacsWiki almost does what I want, but it calls `rgrep` non-interactively whereas I'd like to call it interactively:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GrepFromIsearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright just figured it out — this seems to work:

```
(define-key isearch-mode-map "\C-xg"
  (lambda()
  (interactive)
  (let ((read-regexp-defaults-function (lambda nil
                                         (if isearch-regexp
                                             isearch-string
                                           (regexp-quote isearch-string)))))
    (isearch-exit)
    (call-interactively 'rgrep))))
```